# "Too many concurrent requests for user" error while calling gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

When I am calling gmail api from my  application I am getting the error `"Too many concurrent requests for user"`.

How does google calculate the rate limit?  (I.e Does it include the API request as soon as it gets one or does it also check whether response has been returned then only counts that API hit?)

Below is the error that I am getting from gmail API :

```
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Too many concurrent requests for user",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Too many concurrent requests for user",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- There is no public information about how exactly the rate is being calculated,the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota) specifies

> applies to all requests

- However, the documentaiton specifies which method consumes ho many quota units  and you can estimate the error source by comparing the kind and amount of your requests against the quota of

> Per user rate limit
> 250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts).

For example, if you make 6 `messages.get` and 2 `messages.send` requests per s - this is `6 x 5 + 2 + 100 = 260` quota units - more than allowed.

- The [429 error  "Too many concurrent requests for user"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#concurrent_requests) means that you are making to many parallel requests - either by performing simulatenous requests to multiple API clients or because of using batch requests
- To [resolve this error](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) it is recommended to use exponential backoff to reduce the request rate.

Comment: The golden info here is the exponential backoff https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/handle-errors#exponential-backoff